# usage of this in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, this

in one method to calculate area, while defining a variable, I used *this* and in other (while calculating perimeter) I didn't (as shown in code). What is the difference between 2 variables (with and without *this*?)

```
function Rectangle(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
  this.calcArea = function() {
      this.areaRec = this.height * this.width; //here "this" is used for the variable areaRec to calculate & be returned
      return this.areaRec;
  };


  this.calcPerimeter = function() {
      perimeter = (2*(this.height + this.width)); //here without "this" the varible is caculated and returned; both returns correct result
      return perimeter;
  };
}

var rex = new Rectangle(7,3);

var area = rex.calcArea();
var perimeter = rex.calcPerimeter();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear -- you're using `this` in `calcPerimeter()` in the code you posted. Without `this`, that code would not work.

Comment: In this (heh) case, not much. `this` seems complicated, but is actually pretty straightforward. Take a look at this reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: perimeter is global variable. this.height is variable of Rectangle function

Answer (score 1):

In calcArea you are also setting the result of the calculation on the areaRec property of the Rectangle object (making it accessible on Rectangle.areaRec) aside from returning the result of the calculation. In calcPerimeter you are just returning the result of the calculation (note that calcPerimeter is not defined in the function so it will become a global property on the window object).

Comment: "just returning the result of the calculation" - wrong. The variable was not declared.

Comment: @Qwertiy Did I miss the strict mode somewhere?

Comment: Without strict mode, the variable will become global. See my unswer for more details.

Comment: All 3 ways return the value, but 2 of them do not **just** return. It's not "just" as there is a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's a difference of scope.  You have `perimeter` declared outside of the `Rectangle` function, whereas you don't declare `height` or `width` anywhere, and they're ostensibly declaring themselves on the fly within `Rectangle`.

Try `console.log(height);` outside of the `Rectangle()` function, you should get "undefined" in your console.

If you removed `perimeter =`, `return perimeter` and change the line `var perimeter = rex.calcPerimeter()` to two lines:

`var perimeter;
rex.calcPerimeter();`

then `console.log(perimeter);` after that, you should still get the value that you're returning, since `perimeter`'s scope is global.

Answer (score 0):

When using `this.areaRec =` you are adding a new field to the object referred by `this`. After call to `smth.calcArea()` you'll be able to read `smth.areaRec` from anywhere else.

When using `perimeter =` you are creating such property on `window`. So after the call `smth.calcPerimeter()` you'll be able to read `window.perimeter` or a global variable named `perimeter` from anywhere else.

The right way is to declare the variable like `var perimeter =`. In this case the variable won't leak away from the function and will be just a local variable.